# Reading multiple json files from Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a list of json files which I would like load in parallel.

I can't use `read.json("*")` cause files are not in the same folder and there is no specific pattern I can implement.

I've tried `sc.parallelize(fileList).select(hiveContext.read.json)` but hive context, as expected, doesn't exists in executor.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I found the solution:

```
val text sc.textFile("file1,file2....")
val df = sqlContext.read.json(text)
```

Comment: It accepts multiple files too - sqlContext.read.json(file1, file2)

Comment: Error : 
TypeError: 'property' object is not callable

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can specify directory as a parameter:

```
cat 1.json
{"x": 1.0, "y": 2.0}
{"x": 1.5, "y": 1.0}
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -put 1.json /tmp/test

cat 2.json
{"x": 3.0, "y": 4.0}
{"x": 1.8, "y": 7.0}
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -put 2.json /tmp/test

sqlContext.read.json("/tmp/test").show()
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|1.0|2.0|
|1.5|1.0|
|3.0|4.0|
|1.8|7.0|
+---+---+
```

Comment: yes, but it works only in case all files are under the same directory.

If we have multiple files in different directories, the only way to read them in parallel - is only as text file

Answer (score 2):

Function `json(paths:String*)` takes variable arguments. ([documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@json(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame))

So you can change your code like this:

```scala
sc.read.json(file1, file2, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

a solution for pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local[2]")
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").getOrCreate()

text = sc.textFile("file1,file2...")
ddff = spark.read.json(text)
```