# Spark reading multiple files : double quotes replaced by %22

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have requirements to read random json files in different folders where data has changed. So I can't apply regex to read pattern . I know which are those files and I could list them .But when I form string with all the file path and try reading json  in spark. The double quotes are replaced by %22 and reading files via spark fails. Could any one please help ?

`val FilePath = "\"/path/2019/02/01/*\"" + ","+ "\"path/2019/02/05/*\"" + "\"path/2019/02/24/*\""`

`FilePath:String = "path/2019/02/20/*","path/2019/02/05/*","path/2019/02/24/*"`

Now when I use this variable to read josn files, it fails with error and quotes are replaced by %22.

`spark.read.json(FilePath)`

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: "/path/2019/02/01/*%22,%22/path/2019/02/05/*%22,%22/path/2019/02/24/*%22`

Comment: Why are you including double-quotes in your FilePath string? Have you tried without these?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835989/reading-multiple-json-files-from-spark

Comment: 1. It doesnt work using single quotes
2. I am reading multiple files inside a directory. So not getting how to do it and why %22

Comment: remove ````*```` and try..

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this with an older version of Spark (1.6.0) and it works fine if you supply *separate* paths or wildcard patterns as varargs to the `json` method, i.e.:

```
sqlContext.read.json("foo/*", "bar/*")
```

When you pass multiple patterns in a single string, Spark is trying to construct a single URI from them, which is incorrect, and it will try to URL-encode the quotes characters as %22.

As an aside, trying to create a URI is failing because your string starts with a double-quote, which is an illegal character in that position (RFC 3986):

> Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a
>   letter and followed by any combination of letters, digits, plus
>   ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-").

Answer (score 0):

Add the paths in a list(ex: pathList) and use as below

spark.read.option("basePath", basePath).json(pathList: _*)